# How to annotate field for the right sorting

Tags: django, sorting, model, sql-order-by, annotate

I annotate queryset in Django like this:

```
q_set = q_set.annotate(
            period=Concat(
                ExtractYear(date_field),
                Value(' - '),
                ExtractMonth(date_field),
                output_field=CharField()
            ),
        )
```

But then I get this result:

2022 - 12
2023 - 1
2023 - 10
2023 - 11
2023 - 12
2023 - 2
2023 - 3
2023 - 4
2023 - 5
2023 - 6
2023 - 7
2023 - 8
2023 - 9

But I need to sort it in a right order...

Comment: Please, *don't* do formatting in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* do formatting in the database. Databases should store, manipulate and aggregate *data*, not present data in a nice format. Rendering data or providing it nicely is the task of a view, for example through a serializer.

You can use [**`TruncMonth`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) to convert a date to a date object with the first of the month.

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

q_set = q_set.annotate(period=TruncMonth(date_field))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q_set = q_set.annotate(
            period=Concat(
                ExtractYear(date_field),
                Value(' - '),
                Right(Concat(Value('0'), ExtractMonth(date_field), output_field=CharField()), 2),
                output_field=CharField()
            ),
        )
```

2022 - 12

2023 - 01

2023 - 02

2023 - 03

2023 - 04

2023 - 05

2023 - 06

2023 - 07

2023 - 08

2023 - 09

2023 - 10

2023 - 11
2023 - 12